# Multiply numbers so that their sum matches a specified number

Tags: algorithm

Here is my problem: 
I have N (between 1 and let's say 3 or 4) numbers (integers or doubles, but I have to limit the number of decimals to 2 or 3).
I want to multiply them (and keep proportionality) so that their sum match a certain number.
For example,
I have 0,5 and 2,5 and I want to multiply them to reach 8. 
This is a problem because if I multiply 0,5 by 8/3 and 2,5 by 8/3 and sum them, I won't reach 8 because they are infinite numbers.
So I would need something like : multiply 0,5 by this close number to 8/3 and 1,5 by this other close number to 8/3 so that their sum matches 8.

Thank you!

Comment: i dont get, what the 8/3 is, can you explain with an formated example, what you want to achieve?

Comment: Maybe work with 1/2 and 5/2 num/denominators  to sum, then find your number. Display the result as a fraction, x/y, this way no decimals are lost.

Comment: @jarl 8/3 = 8/(0,5+2,5). With easy numbers, like 1 and 3, I want to find that I can multiply both numbers with 2 (because 1*2 + 3*2 = 8), so that I will be able to display 2 and 6.

Comment: @RingØ I need to get literal values, not fraction. I want to keep a certain proportionality (not a problem if not perfect), and the results I get can be a little rounded if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so your problem is the following:

```
x_1 * y + x_2 * y = z
```

When x_1 and x_2 are the numbers that you want to multiply by y to reach z, right?

When you divide this by y you will receive

```
x_1 + x_2 = z / y
```

So when you sum x_1 and x_2 you will find out which z/y you need.
Due to the fact that you know z, you have to multiply the result with y and divide that with your sum (x_1 + x_2) to know z.

Little example:

You want to multiply x_1 (=3) and x_2 (=2,5) with y to get z (=11).

```
x_1 + x_2 = 5,5 = 11 / y
```

Multiplied with y and divided with 5,5 you receive:

```
5,5 = 11 / y | * y
5,5y = 11 | / 5,5
y = 2
```

So you know that you have to multiply it with 2 to get the result.
To solve your problem in the beginning, you just have to round the result.

This (of course) is also working for more x-values than two.

When you recognize that you have to take care of fractions you can`t handle, than you have to round them. So my suggestion is to round the result down, when you rounded y up (and vice versa).

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: Sorry, I am not allowed to comment up to now so I have to ask in this way

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173/).

Comment: Hello, yes this is regarding an implementation, but I have not chose the language yet, probably C#. But I don't think this will be difficult to code once I have the algorithm. :)

Comment: @HerTesla thx for your answer. If you use my numbers, you get 0,5+2,5 = 3 = 8/y. As I can't keep the fraction, what is y?

Comment: y is the multiplier you need so that 0,5 * y + 2,5 * y = 8. So 3 = 8/y -> 3y = 8 -> y = 8/3

Comment: Ahh now I understood your question - 8/3 is not a valid answer for you, right? You need to round this to a valid double value (lets say 2,67) and use this instead. With this you should get a result of 8,01. So maybe you need to round this result down, when you rounded the y up - know what I mean?

Comment: Yes I see what you mean, and that is what I am looking for. :)

Comment: When this is your answer, it would be really nice when you can select this answer as accepted :-) Thanks

Comment: " So maybe you need to round this result down, when you rounded the y up" this is what I am looking for, not what you explained in your answer :)